# Emulating "Swiss style" shaded relief with ArcGIS tools?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, cartography, shaded-relief

Is there a way to create a Swiss style (or other hand-shaded-like styles) shaded relief from a dem using ArcGIS tools alone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- (2008) [Updated hillshade toolbox](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/mapping/updated-hillshade-toolbox/) by Aileen Buckley, Mapping Center Lead, Esri. Swiss style shaded relief and Multi directional oblique weighted (MDOW) relief toolboxes for ArcGIS 9.2 and 9.3
- (2010) [Using curvature rasters to enhance terrain representation](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/imagery/using-curvature-rasters-to-enhance-terrain-representation/?rmedium=redirect&rsource=/esri/arcgis/2010/10/27/using-curvature-rasters-to-enhance-terrain-representation) by Aileen Buckley, Mapping Center Lead, Esri. *"using curvature rasters with hillshaded surfaces helps to capture local variations ... to help us to better see the detail in the high slope areas"*
- (2014) [Introducing Esri’s Next Generation Hillshade](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-living-atlas/imagery/introducing-esris-next-generation-hillshade/?rmedium=redirect&rsource=/esri/arcgis/2014/07/14/introducing-esris-next-generation-hillshade) by Rajinder Nagi, Esri. *"The Multi-Directional Hillshade is available on ArcGIS Online and can be easily added to your desktop or web apps. It is currently implemented as a custom raster function on the World Elevation Service, and requires an ArcGIS Organizational subscription account to access."*
- (2015) [Take your terrain mapping to new heights](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/analytics/take-your-terrain-mapping-to-new-heights/) by Kenneth Field, Senior Cartographic Product Engineer, and  Linda Beale, Esri. A culmination of hillshade and terrain research from many years in a single package. Includes a zip file from ArcGIS Online that contains the toolbox, sample data, documentation and also an ArcMap Map Document (v10.x) and ArcGIS Pro Project.
- (2018) Multi-directional hillshade function is now available out-of-the-box in ArcGIS Pro (1.4 or later) and ArcMap 10.6. It can be invoked by choosing the Multidirectional option from drop down menu of Hillshade Type parameter (in Image Analysis function editor after applying the Hillshade).

Comment: I tried the Swiss hillshade tools in several different situations and it does not produce results that one could call "Swiss" hillshading. There is some minor smoothing in flat areas that's about it.

Comment: Is the first part still valid?  I could not find the Hillshade tools using "Yes, http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=arcgisResources.gateway.  
Goto Model/Scripts tab then to Hillshade tools"

Comment: @PolyGeo I updated the broken links, added summaries, and new information

Answer (score 3):

This student specifically used a color scheme that ranged from "Yucca Yellow" to "Larkspur Blue" to emphasize the Swiss effect in her hillshade.

http://downloads2.esri.com/MappingCenter2007/resources/workshops/TerrainRep_2008_CreateABlue-YellowHillshade.doc

http://www.reliefshading.com/colours/yellow-tone/