# The best GIS book!

Tags: references

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GIS Pros - what lives on your bookshelf?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202/gis-pros-what-lives-on-your-bookshelf)

Which book do you think is best for GIS with theoretical bases?