# What is the single most influential book every GIS professional should read?

Tags: references

If you could go back in time and tell yourself to read a specific book/text/guide/tutorial at the beginning of your career as a gis-developer, which book would it be?

I expect this list to be varied and to cover a wide range of things.

---

This same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read) was once asked at stackoverflow for programming topics, and it has been considered by some as "one of the most important question ever asked on stackoverflow".
So I decided to bring this question to serve our needs here at gis.stackexchange.

Comment: This needs to be CW.

Comment: Also: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202/gis-pros-what-lives-on-your-bookshelf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do like [How to Lie with Maps](http://www.press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/H/bo3696845.html).

Comment: It's from the same author but, being a political animal, I always preferred Bushmanders and Bullwinkles.

Comment: This was on the first slide of the first GIS lecture I ever had.

Comment: Stackexchange sent me a complaint that this answer might be removed for being too short. A short answer can be a full answer. And, it has been fine for the last four years. The voting system should control content, not some moderator with arbitrary policies. If you take it down I will quit using the site.

Answer (score 2):

[GIS for Web Developers: Adding Where to Your Web Applications by Scott Davis, The Pragmatic Programmers, 2007, ISBN: 0-9745140-9-8](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780974514093)

Comment: I read this, and was a good read, although I need the opposite book.  Web Development for GIS Analysts.

Answer (score 0):

One of my old favourites is [The Nature of Maps](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226722813), by Robinson and Petchenik.

Older, and more academic, but I like it, and it is supposed to be a ground-breaker in its day.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have about 2 yards of cooler, more fun books related to GIS... I think ["Modeling our World"](http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=27) by ESRI Press is a great foundation for the aspiring map geek.