# Seeking GIS-related magazines and monthly papers

Tags: open-source-gis, references

Can you recommend some magazines or other GIS-related papers (printed or digital) which are released on a monthly basis (or every 2-3 months);

I am looking to keep in touch with the GIS fast-growing world and I would prefer something other than books or websites.

Maybe some of you already have a subscription at some magazine.

I am quite interested in Open Source Software but not only.

This post would be the magazine equivalent to another one with useful information about books: [What books, journals, and electronic resources are most valuable for expanding knowledge of GIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202/what-books-journals-electronic-resources-are-most-valuable-for-expanding-geogr)

Answer (score 7):

You can try following :

[Arc-News](http://www.esri.com/esri-news/arcnews) (For ESRI related and general GIS news)

[Directions Magazine](http://www.directionsmag.com/) (For latest update and webinars information)

[GIS Development](http://www.geospatialworld.net/) (for latest news and software reviews)

[GISlounge.com](http://www.gislounge.com/open-source-gis-applications/) ,[giscafe.com](http://www.giscafe.com/) (For latest update, GIS news etc)

Few Blogs

[Mapperz - The Mapping News Blog](http://mapperz.blogspot.in/)

James Fee : [spatiallyadjusted.com](http://spatiallyadjusted.com/)

GIS training related : [geospatialtraining.com/blog/](http://geospatialtraining.com/blog/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one

[The Geospatial Resource Portal](http://www.geospatialworld.net/magazine/ymag.aspx?id=2012_Geospatial%20World%20Magzine)