# Learning classical geography - recommended literature etc

Tags: cartography, geography, geodesy, references

I've been working in the field of GIS for a few years now, and there are some disciplines of knowledge where I lack a good degree of education.

My educational background is that I've studied computer engineering, and completed a bachelor degree, so I'm well at ease with any technical aspect of the job that comes up. Setting up servers, programming/scripting etc.

But what **I lack is a good solid knowledge about cartography, geodesy and similar topics** that fall within the domain of geography, which is of course a central aspect of the job.

Some subjects I would like to know more about are, for example, cartography, geodesy, datum, reference ellipsoid, the geoid, map projections, spatial reference systems.

So **what I would like you to do is to point me to some good literature and other resources where I can learn about these topics**. Don't be afraid of suggesting any authoritative "bibles" that hold Humanity's accumulated knowledge in these fields, I'd rather choose that instead of some beginners-level book that only gives an introductory knowing.

Comment: Have you seen this related question "What books, journals, electronic resources are most valuable for expanding Geographic Information knowledge"?: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/202/8104

Comment: @Aaron: Thanks, that seems like a really useful link. But I've sifted through the answers and most books seem to have a more technical orientation, while I am looking more to learn about the "theoretical framework" of geography. There's one exception though, J. Snyder's "Map Projections: A Working Manual" seems like a book that's quite on the spot on a few things I'm looking for.

Comment: @Vincent, If you didn't check out the the Geospatial Analysis suggestion (http://www.spatialanalysisonline.com) in Aaron's link, I strongly recommend that you do. I slept with this book under my pillow while pursuing a master's degree in GIS. There is pretty detailed information about theory, and if you need to delve deeper, you can explore the book's references.

How to Lie with Maps is also good.

Comment: May i suggest that the overall term for our discipline is not *geography*, for that covers a very broader range of large topics itself, but that it is *geomatics*? Or, if you wish to reference geography, it is *technical* geography (to distinguish it from *physical* geography, *human* geography, and *regional* geography)?

Answer (score 1):

On **Geodesy**:

*Geodesy*, 3rd edition, W Torge. de Gruyter, 2011.

*Geodesy, the concepts*, 2nd edition, P Vaníček & EJ Krakiwsky. Elsevier Science, 1987.

*Geodesy*, 4th edition, G Bomford. Clarendon Press, 1980.

On **Projections**:

*Map Projections: A Working Manual*, JP Snyder. USGS, 1987.

[Map Projections and Geodetic Coordinate Systems](http://www.uni-stuttgart.de/gi/geoengine/mappro/lecturenotes.pdf), Lecture notes, F Krumm, Stuttgart University, 2014.

On **Cartography**:

*Elements of Cartography*, 6th edition, AH Robinson, JL Morrison, PC Muehrcke, AJ Kimerling & SC Guptill. Wyley, 1995.

On **Surveying**:

*Elementary Surveying*, 9th edition, PR Wolf & RC Brinker. Land Surveyors Pubs, 1997.

*Practical Surveying and Computations*, 2nd edition, AL Allen. Butterworth-Heinemann, 1993.

On **Photogrammetry and Remote Sensing**:

*Elements of Photogrammetry with Application in GIS*, 4th edition, PR Wolf, B DeWitt & B Wilkinson. McGraw-Hill, 2014.

*Remote Sensing, 
Models and Methods for Image Processing*, 3rd edition, RA Schowengerdt. Elsevier, 2007.

*Remote Sensing: Principles and Interpretation*, 3rd edition, FF Sabins. Waveland, 2007.

On **Database Systems**:

*An Introduction to Database Systems*, 8th edition, CJ Date. Pearson, 2003.

On **Computer Graphics**:

*Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice*, 3rd edition, JF Hughes, A van Dam, M McGuire, JD Foley, SK Feiner & K Akeley. 2013.

Comment: None on GIS! Who needs them, if you're into the fundamentals?